# How do I improve my Buddhabrot rendering?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rendering, fractals

I am trying to create a beautiful render of the Buddhabrot fractal with a mathematical background and I want to make it faster and more importantly, prettier. I have a script (buddhabrot_functions) and a main program. It basically splits the image into chunks, which I then later glue together. I have found the code to be rather slow, is there some way that I am missing to make it faster? Also, when I'm running more chunks there seems to be large yellow squares towards the outside of the image and rather noticable inconsistencies at the borders of the chunks.

I have a script (buddhabrot_functions) and a main program. It basically splits the image into chunks, which I then later glue together. I have found the code to be rather slow, is there some way that I am missing to make it faster? Also, when I'm running more chunks there seems to be large yellow squares towards the outside of the image and rather noticable inconsistencies at the borders of the chunks.

This is the script:

```
def buddhabrot(c, max_iter):
    z = c
    trajectory = [c]
    for i in range(max_iter):
        if abs(z) > 4.0:
            return trajectory
        z = z*z + c
        trajectory.append(z)
    return []

def buddhabrot_helper(inputs):
    c, max_iter = inputs
    return buddhabrot(c, max_iter)
```

and this is the main program:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from PIL import Image
from buddhabrot_functions import buddhabrot_helper
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm


RESOLUTION =10000
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = -2.0, 1.0, -1.5, 1.5
width = xmax - xmin
height = ymax - ymin
CHUNK_SIZE = 5000
max_iter = 100000

def calculate_and_save_chunk(i, j):
    xmin_chunk = xmin + i * width * CHUNK_SIZE / RESOLUTION
    xmax_chunk = xmin + (i + 1) * width * CHUNK_SIZE / RESOLUTION
    ymin_chunk = ymin + j * height * CHUNK_SIZE / RESOLUTION
    ymax_chunk = ymin + (j + 1) * height * CHUNK_SIZE / RESOLUTION

    r1 = np.linspace(xmin_chunk, xmax_chunk, CHUNK_SIZE)
    r2 = np.linspace(ymin_chunk, ymax_chunk, CHUNK_SIZE)
    meshgrid = np.meshgrid(r1, r2)

    pixels = [(complex(r, i), max_iter) for r, i in zip(np.ravel(meshgrid[0]), np.ravel(meshgrid[1]))]
    
    pool = Pool()
    trajectories = pool.map(buddhabrot_helper, pixels)
    pool.close()

    # Initialize density map
    density = np.zeros((CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE))

    for trajectory in trajectories:
        for z in trajectory:
            x, y = (z.real - xmin_chunk) * CHUNK_SIZE / (xmax_chunk - xmin_chunk), (z.imag - ymin_chunk) * CHUNK_SIZE / (ymax_chunk - ymin_chunk)
            if 0 <= x < CHUNK_SIZE and 0 <= y < CHUNK_SIZE:
                density[int(x), int(y)] += 1

    density = np.sqrt(density) 

    density = (density - np.min(density)) / (np.max(density) - np.min(density))
    
    color_data = cm.viridis(density)
    img = Image.fromarray((255 * color_data).astype(np.uint8))

    
    img.save(f"buddhabrot_{i}_{j}.png")


for i in range(RESOLUTION // CHUNK_SIZE):
    for j in range(RESOLUTION // CHUNK_SIZE):
        calculate_and_save_chunk(i, j)
```

I definitely want to stick to this project and Python, can someone help me out? Also, I can not use GPU for my code.

Comment: One observation: for each chunk you do `density = (density - np.min(density)) / (np.max(density) - np.min(density))` then use that "scaled" density to determine the pixel colours for that chunk. That means that pixels with the same "unscaled" density in different chunks will end up with different "scaled" densities and therefore different colours. This might be what causes inconsistencies at the chunk borders.

Comment: Another observation: when the trajectory crosses a chunk boundary - i.e. the trajectory contains points that are not in the same chunk as the trajectory's starting point - I think those are not included in the result because of `if 0 <= x < CHUNK_SIZE and 0 <= y < CHUNK_SIZE:` ?

Comment: @slothrop Yes, i have thought of both, I do not know how to fix either, any ideas?

Comment: Possible plan: At the chunk level you could produce (a) the `trajectories` and (b) an unscaled `density` matrix which covers all pixels within the image (not just the chunk). Then, sum the density matrices across all chunks, and do the remaining steps (sqrt -> scale -> produce image)